# C# How to Add the String Value of CheckBox into Parameters

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a Column Name Gender which determine if the user is a male/female, What i want is when i choose to one of the checkbox, the value that database get is Male or Female not 1 or 0

```
private void btn_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var con = SQLConnection.GetConnection())
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_firstname.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_lastname.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_age.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_contact.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_email.Text))
            {
                MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "Please input the Required Fields", "System Message:", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            }
            else
            {
              SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand(" INSERT into admin_customerss (Firstname,Lastname,Age,Gender,Contactnumber,Email)  values (@Firstname, @Lastname, @Age, @Gender, @Contactnumber, @Email)", con);
                selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Firstname", txt_firstname.Text);
                selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lastname", txt_lastname.Text);
                selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", txt_age.Text);
                selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", cbox_male.Checked);                
                selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contactnumber", txt_contact.Text);
                selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txt_email.Text);
                selectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Added successfully", "SIMS", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);   
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: And what is the datatype of the field Gender on the database's table?

Comment: I used Varchar datatype

Comment: Note that the [tag:visual-studio] tag description says *"DO NOT use this tag on questions regarding code which merely happened to be written in Visual Studio."* Please [edit] your question to remove it.

Comment: Also note that `SqlCommand` is `IDisposable` so should be in a `using` block.

Answer (score 0):

Your insert values should always be compatible with the datatype of the database field.

If the datatype of the Gender field is NVarChar or VarChar you just need to change a single line in your code

```
selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", (cbox_male.Checked ? "Male" : "Female"));
```

but if you have a Bit field then you can only store 1 or 0. Is then up to you to correctly convert these values when you want to display them

Consider also that `AddWithValue` is a useful shortcut, but [they have proved how dangerous it is](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

If possible use (still one line but more precise)

```
selectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Gender", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =   (cbox_male.Checked ? "Male" : "Female"));
```

Comment: Thank you for the guide sir, My problem is now Fix :)